# How to calculate Latency and Bandwidth in Java Microbenchmark tests

Tags: performance, microbenchmark, jmh

We are planning implementing Microbenchmark tests for our java based springboot project for which we are planning to leverage JMH.

We are in need of validating Latency and Bandwidth metric and not sure how to fetch these from JMH.

Can someone suggest a sample code or reference?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JMH measures throughput, not bandwidth.

Here's the example of measuring costs of Spring Boot-based application start-up: https://github.com/stsypanov/spring-boot-benchmark

And here are various examples of Spring-related measurements with JMH: https://github.com/stsypanov/spring-benchmark (e.g. [this benchmark](https://github.com/stsypanov/spring-benchmark/blob/master/src/main/java/org/tsypanov/sb/aspect/benchmark/AspectPrototypeBenchmark.java) allows to measure costs of getting a new prototype-scoped bean from application context. As of your question if you want to measure latency (i.e. average execution time of benchmarked method) you use the mentioned benchmark as is. If you want to measure throughput then just change

```java
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
```

to

```java
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

The second annotation set tells JMH to print how many times the method can be called within a second.